# fscanf() wont read data after done counting lines C

Tags: c

first of all thanks to Stack Overflow, I have a problem in my C Code in reading files using fscanf().

```
FILE *edit = fopen("test.txt", "r");

int id_temp;
fscanf(edit, "%d", &id_temp);
printf("%d\n", id_temp);
fclose(edit);
system("pause");
```

I can read it in this way but when I add on counting lines,

```
FILE *edit = fopen("test.txt", "w");
char ch;
int count = 0;

do
{
    ch = fgetc(edit);
    if (ch == '\n') count++;
} while (ch != EOF);

printf("Total number of lines %d\n", count);

int id_temp = 0;
fscanf(edit, "%d", &id_temp);
printf("%d\n", id_temp);
fclose(edit);
system("pause");
```

The id_temp will print 0 instead of read the number from the file itself. While on the first scenario, it prints me 2 (correct).

Thank you for your time, Any idea guys?

Comment: You didn't rewind the file, so the `fscanf()` is working on nothing.  It failed; you didn't check that it told you it failed.  Also, `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  You'll need to fix that.

Comment: Yeah i changed fgetc() to int, and how to rewind the file

Comment: `rewind(edit);`?

Comment: Worth noting, if applicable your algorithm also doesn't account for the potential final line that does *not* end with a newline (but *does* end with EOF). If your file has content after the final newline it will be ignored and not counted as a line.

Comment: Ok I just add 'rewind(edit)' after counting lines and it works, Thanks @Jonathan Leffler

Comment: `FILE *edit = fopen("test.txt", "w");` --> `FILE *edit = fopen("test.txt", "r");`